# How to show dynamic multi column in dropdown using angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want show a multiple column in a dropdown using angular.

```
<ng-select
  [items]="roleCategory$ | async"
  [addTag]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRole"
  bindLabel="roleCategory"
  bindValue="roleCategory"
  placeholder="Select"
  [clearable]=true
  [searchable]=true
  [dropdownPosition]="'down'"
          </ng-select>
```

[image]

I want to show a dynamic value in multiple column as mentioned above picture.
Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: That's a styling issue. Open chrome pree f12 then inspect element. Change the top css element style to get what you want. Then put it into your component. Do you know Css?

Comment: Thanks for the reply john. I ctries to achoeve through css but couldnt achieve it for dynamic values. if i hardcode dropdown values in html it works. but for me the dropdown datas are coming from backend. so thought of cchecking that somebpdy else faced the same situation

Comment: Dynamic values from back end yes, but once the browser displays something those values are NOT dynamic, they are real values which something like { display:Grid; grid-template-columns : 1fr 1fr 1fr } will autoformat, i'm not sure why you could not find that element in the chrome debugger. Just right click on the element and pick inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this through custom css by findind odd and even div and apply style.Please find the below sample. it may help someone.

```
.ng-select.solution-list-dropdown > .ng-dropdown-panel {
 width: 570px;
 left: -86%;
 font-family: $ng-font-family;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid $ng-select-border;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
 &.ng-select-bottom {
   top: 100%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
   border-top-color: $ng-select-border;
   margin-top: -1px;
   .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
     .ng-option {
       &:last-child {
         border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
         border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
       }
     }
   }
 }
 &.ng-select-top {
   bottom: 100%;
   border-top-right-radius: 20px;
   border-top-left-radius: 20px;
   border-bottom-color: $ng-select-border;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
   .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
     .ng-option {
       &:first-child {
         border-top-right-radius: 20px;
         border-top-left-radius: 20px;
       }
     }
   }
 }
 .ng-dropdown-header {
   border-bottom: 1px solid $ng-select-border;
   padding: 5px 7px;
 }
 .ng-dropdown-footer {
   border-top: 1px solid $ng-select-border;
   padding: 5px 7px;
 }
 .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
   .ng-optgroup {
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
     padding: 8px 30px;
     font-weight: 500;
     color: #6D7895;
     cursor: pointer;
     &.ng-option-disabled {
       cursor: default;
     }
     &.ng-option-marked {
       background-color: $ng-select-marked;
     }
     &.ng-option-selected, &.ng-option-selected.ng-option-marked {
       background-color: $ng-select-selected;
       font-weight: 500;
     }
   }
   .ng-option {
     background-color: white;
     color: var(--color-lynch);
     padding: 8px 30px;
     &.ng-option-selected, &.ng-option-selected.ng-option-marked {
       color: $ng-select-primary-text;
       background-color: $ng-select-selected;
       z-index: -100;
       .ng-option-label {
         font-weight: 500;
       }
     }
     &.ng-option-marked {
       background-color: $ng-select-marked;
       color: $ng-select-primary-text;
     }
     &.ng-option-disabled {
       color: lighten($ng-select-primary-text, 60);
     }
     &.ng-option-child {
       padding-left: 22px;
       @include rtl {
         padding-right: 22px;
         padding-left: 0;
       }
     }
     &.ng-option:nth-child(odd){
       width: 40%;
       float: left;
       //background-color: #efefef;
     }
     &.ng-option:nth-child(even){
       //background-color: #efefef;
     }
     .ng-tag-label {
       font-size: 80%;
       font-weight: 500;
       padding-right: 5px;
       @include rtl {
         padding-left: 5px;
         padding-right: 0;
       }
     }
   }
 }

 @include rtl {
   direction: rtl;
   text-align: right;
 }
}
```